# WCF Project - EntityFramework 5.0.0 ' 'Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework...' Error

Tags: wcf, configuration, entity-framework-5

I have a WCF Service application that uses EntityFramework 5.0.0 and when I called the method that uses the EDMX framework I get the below given message.

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. See server logs for more details.

Here are my config snippets:

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

**Web.config**

```
<assemblyBinding>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Am I missing anything? What do I have to check?

Help Please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.NET 4.5 is required. However, EF5 will run on .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168035/entity-framework-5-0-minimum-net-framework-version-required-net-4-0-or-4-5)
So you have to check that IIS Application pool is configured to support .Net FrameWork 4.0.
For example: Sharepoint 2010 requires ASP.Net 3.5, so it does not support EF5.

Comment: Your have to run Internet Information Service(IIS) Manger. Then navigate to "Your Server"-> "Application Pools". Here find application pool running your WCF application. Open it's context menu (right mouse button click) ->Base Settings->.Net Framework version

Comment: I got to where you told me, I am using the SharePoint - 80 site to access my WCF service. The version is 4.0.30319.

Comment: Your tip on FusionLog helped me alot.. I found out that the Service is searching for the dll in 80/bin. After I copied it there.. Im getting another error(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20129769/cant-find-entity-framework-connection-string-in-app-config). Thanks getting me over this hurdle!

Answer (score 0):

Summary with the help of @Ruslan-Dayanov:

Configure and Use the Fusion Log Viewer to see where the service looks for the dll. Make sure the dll is available in that location.

**References**

- How to configure Fusion Log: [Hanselman's Guide](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)
- MSDN article on Fusion Log Viewer: [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx)