# ASP.NET cannot enable migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem enabling migrations on my ASP.net MVC project. 
Anybody help please. 
error is as following:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName HRHR.Models.ListofvacanciesEntities Checking if the context targets an existing database... 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception.
---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. 
---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize 
---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section compilation. (C:\Users\Taras\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\HRHR\HRHR\tmpAE68.tmp line 7)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
       at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
       at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_ConnectionStrings()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForAssembly(Assembly assemblyHint, Type contextTypeHint)
       at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbConfigurationManager.EnsureLoadedForContext(Type contextType)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..cctor()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1..ctor()
       at HRHR.Migrations.Configuration..ctor() in C:\Users\Taras\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\HRHR\HRHR\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 10
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.MigrationsConfigurationFinder.FindMigrationsConfiguration(Type contextType, String configurationTypeName, Func`2 noType, Func`3 multipleTypes, Func`3 noTypeWithName, Func`3 multipleTypesWithName)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
       at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
       at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
       at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
    The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an exception.
```

**This is my Configuration.cs:**

```
namespace HRHR.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<HRHR.Models.ListofvacanciesEntities>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(HRHR.Models.ListofvacanciesEntities context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my Web.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="WebMatrix.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <add assembly="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-HRHR-20160427123011.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-HRHR-20160427123011;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
    <add name="ListofvacanciesEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DataForSystem.csdl|res://*/Models.DataForSystem.ssdl|res://*/Models.DataForSystem.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Listofvacancies;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />    
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

</configuration>
```

[my solution explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O4dm.jpg)

Comment: Issue seems to be with App.config section: Unrecognized configuration section compilation.

Comment: James P, thank you for your time for reading my issue. I have just added Configuration.cs file and Web.config.

Comment: Is your edmx in same project as MVC application?

Comment: James P, Yes. I have added [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9O4dm.jpg) for my solution explorer.

Comment: Think its probably issue with connect string see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213943/net-4-how-to-configure-edmx-file-in-other-assembly-in-web-config

Comment: I tried to solve my issue as you recommended me but it hasn't helped.
Also, I couldn't found __MigrationHistory table.
Could you recommend how can I solve it?

Comment: James P, I've found a solution for my issue. Thank for your answers anyway.

Comment: Ok, glad you resolved issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for my issue.
Please check does your project was created with code first or database first.
If you have database first you've got problem like me. Just follow this link:
http://devgush.com/2014/02/24/migrating-a-project-from-database-first-to-code-first/
Sorry for my bad English)